# what grid system does swivel.com use?

Tags: javascript, grid

What grid library does swivel.com use?  It looks pretty nice.  Is it made inhouse? In other words, what good JS grid libraries are available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's made inhouse with prototype.  not that much actual scriptaculous stuff is needed for the grid though.  we initially looked at dojo's grid when we started (about 6 months ago) and it didn't do as much as we needed and we would've had to customize the hell out of it anyway.  mootools might have a decent one now too.

Answer (score 0):

Swivel is a Ruby on Rails site and is using Prototype and script.aculo.us. The CSS doesn't look like any particular system that I recognize but that's not surprising. I think rolling your own CSS is way more common than using some CSS "framework".

Comment: They use scriptaculous to generate the Excel like grids too?